# Group of perfect Hamming codes

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, error-propagation

I read that a group of perfect Hamming code is defined as $[2^r-1,2^r-r-1,3]$ for any integer $r\geq 2$.

To be perfect such codes should satisfy the following equivalence (derived from the Hamming bound):
$$\sum_{j=0}^r\binom{2^r - 1}{j} = 2^{r}$$
which is in contradiction with the fact that $r\geq2$.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: What you are missing is a comprehensible question. I really don't know what you are asking.

Comment: It regards error-correction and hamming codes. There were no labels in this sense. Maybe this page of stack exchange is not appropriate..

Comment: This is a good place to ask questions about error-correction and Hamming codes. But I don't see where you have asked a question.

Comment: I couldn't get how the equivalence I wrote were valid. In fact it was not.

Comment: OK. Please edit the body of your question so as to make it clear that that's what the question is about. Users shouldn't have to traipse through the comments to understand the question.

Comment: Now it should be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear $[n,k,d]_q$-code is perfect if and only if
$$
q^{n-k}=\sum_{i=0}^{(d-1)/2}\binom{n}{i}(q-1)^i.
$$
In the case of a binary Hamming code, $n=2^r-1$, $k=2^r-r-1$ and $d=3$, $q=2$. So this gives
$$
2^r=\sum_{i=0}^1\binom{2^r-1}{i}.
$$
Do you see your mistake?

Comment: Yes, I mixed up the concept of distance $d$ with the radius $r$.. thank you!